# Interpretation of lag-response curve

Tags: time-series, generalized-linear-model, biostatistics, distributed-lag

Here Dr. Gasparrini presents a lag-response curve for the IRR of acute myocardial infarction following flu episode compared to those not experiencing a flu episode.

https://youtu.be/EiDxtgTvlak?t=3229

My assumption is that the model is expressed as a quasipoisson or poisson GLM with the following effects:

$$ \log p(\text{AMI}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 t_1 + \beta_2 t_2 \ldots \beta_p t_p  $$

Where there is one observation per subject, the event $\text{AMI}$ is a binary 0,1 variable meaning occurrence of infarct, or normal cardiac function. Time $t = \{t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_p\}$ is a discrete, categorical expression of the time series expressed in lags prior to evaluation of AMI at which if a subject had active flu infection, evaluates to 1, 0 otherwise.

He then interprets the curve as showing a high instantaneous risk of flu, meaning that subjects are highly likely to experience AMI immediately after flu rather than a week or so out. See figure 1.

[image]

However, in what sense are the lags conditional on the other lags? Meaning if we considered a triangular representation of the distributed lags and their associated models:

$$ \begin{array}{c|ccccc}
& t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & \ldots & t_p \\ \hline
M_1 & \beta_{11} & & & & \\
M_2 & \beta_{21} & \beta_{22}& & & \\
M_3 & \beta_{31} & \beta_{32}& \beta_{33}& & \\
\ldots&&&&&\\
M_p & \beta_{p1} & \beta_{p2}& \beta_{p3}& \cdots& \beta_{pp}\\
\end{array}$$

If we wanted to test the hypothesis that the highest risk for AMI was immediately following flu, we would need to test the nested model $M_1$ against $M_p$?

Comment: I can't really answer your question, but the model is a conditional Poisson GLM with distributed lags. Mr. Gasparrini is an expert for distributed lag non-linear models. I suspect that you find more information in the vignette "Distributed lag linear and non-linear models for time series data" of his R package `dlnm`.